# Avoid loop unrolling for executing sequential data transfer in verilog

Tags: loops, verilog, execution, sequential

I need to execute a set of codes sequentially in verilog
The problem is that i tried to give looping using for loop/ generate for loop. In for loop I strongly believe that loop unrolling takes place and every thing happens in parallel. Could you please suggest me how to implement the sequential execution of for loop so that I can apply the same concept for carrying out repeated process? Or Is there any other technique which can be employed for implementing sequential procedure? I am using the process for transferring  multiple byte of data using UART.

Comment: verilog is a concurrent language. The only thing which is executed sequentially are statements **inside** an `always`  block. The `always` blocks themselves are executed at will. Same for internals of a generate block. You choose a wrong language. In verilog you need to synchronize everything with flops to do *sequential* actions.

Comment: I am not sure about this, but based on your description, it seems that you are not talking about hardware, rather than a software. If that is true, then Verilog might not be the ideal language for that.

Answer (score 0):

The usual technique for implementing a sequential procedure in hardware is building a state machine with a case statement.

```
  integer state, next_state;
  parameter S0 = 0, S1 = 1, S2 = 2;
  always @(posedge clock) state <= next_state;
  always @(*)
     case(state)
       S0: begin
           // ... code for sequence 0
           next_state = S1;
           end
      S1: begin
           // ... code for sequence 1
           next_state = S2;
           end
      S2: begin
           // ... code for sequence 2
           next_state = S0;
           end
      endcase
```

But for data transfer, this is a very inefficient use of hardware. Think of your data as a car on a factory assembly line. Although the car goes through a sequential series of stage in its manufacture, each stage of the factory is going through a repetitive series of the same steps on different cars, with each stage working in parallel. That is how you should be describing your hardware to a synthesis tool. There are some tools just now beginning to appear that take a sequential description and parallelize it, but those are far from general available right now.